# Unable to bind SVG image in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am unable to bind svg image in xamarin.forms gridview.  I have a grid view and I want to add 9 row/column with .SVG images

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#BF4E21" Spacing="1">
    <StackLayout>
        <abstractions:SvgImage HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding CoolMaskSvgPath}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Men" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

---

```
public Assembly SvgAssembly => typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
public string CoolMaskSvgPath => "001-travel-1.svg";

public LookUp()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: you can only bind to public properties

Comment: Could you please explain it, means what should i do for this type of problem.

Comment: You must change the `CoolMaskSvgPath` and `SvgAssembly` to a property signature. Like this: `public string CoolMaskSvgPath { get => "001-travel-1.svg"; }`

Comment: public string CoolMaskSvgPath { get => "StoreProject.Images.001-travel-1.svg"; }

I am getting Error for this line

Comment: public string CoolMaskSvgPath => "001-travel-1.svg"; Already have get property